# Is eating watermelon after milk bad?

Tags: nutrition, healthcare, milk, fruit

It’s a local “myth” here in Iran that eating watermelon and milk (or any fatty food in general) is bad (as in it can cause stomachache or a bloated stomach etc). How true is this?

My web searches around suggest this myth also exists in India, and there are anecdotal stories on both sides.

For example, see [Here's Why Ayurveda Says You Should Avoid Drinking Milk After Having Watermelon](https://food.ndtv.com/food-drinks/heres-why-ayurveda-says-you-should-avoid-drinking-milk-after-having-watermelon-1875279).

Comment: I'm not sure about the loss of motion, but it can certainly cause gastro-intestinal issues. The main driver, that I'm aware of, is the solidification of fats in the milk caused by the acid in the watermelon. You wouldn't drink milk and lemon juice right? Watermelon is sweeter, but still has some acidity. Check out the definition of curdle - this is what happens to the milk fats, and my understanding is this causes the fats to become harder to digest, potentially leading the negative effects mentioned in that article. Not an answer because I have no sources.

Comment: @TCooper Would that happen with semi-solid yoghurt as well?

Comment: I can confirm this belief exists among some Indians. Some of my Indian coworkers bawk at the idea of consuming any citrus fruit within 5-10 minutes of consuming milk.

Comment: @TCooper whatever you eat or drink is going into stomach acid, so why would that make a difference?